# Have multiple public methods shortened by calling private

Tags: java

I have multiple public methods that check for discounts, I am wanting to not repeat the code multiple times and just have the bulk of the code in a private method that the public methods can access. Here is the code. Is this possible?

```
public static boolean isE1(WebOrder order)
  {
  if(order.getPromos().stream().filter(i -> E1.contains(i.toUpperCase())).findFirst().isPresent())
  {
     return true;
  }
  else
  {
     List<Discount> discounts = new LinkedList<>();

     order.getItems().forEach(i -> discounts.addAll(i.getDiscounts()));

     if(!discounts.isEmpty())
     {
        return discounts.stream()
           .filter(i -> E1.contains(i.getCode().toUpperCase()))
           .findFirst()
           .isPresent();
     }
     else
     {
        return false;
     }
  }
}
   public static boolean isE2(WebOrder order)
   {
  if(order.getPromos().stream().filter(i -> E2.contains(i.toUpperCase())).findFirst().isPresent())
  {
     return true;
  }
  else
  {
     List<Discount> discounts = new LinkedList<>();

     order.getItems().forEach(i -> discounts.addAll(i.getDiscounts()));

     if(!discounts.isEmpty())
     {
        return discounts.stream()
              .filter(i -> E2.contains(i.getCode().toUpperCase()))
              .findFirst()
              .isPresent();
     }
     else
     {
        return false;
     }
  }
```

}

Comment: yes? What are you asking, specifically?

Comment: Sure they can. Give it a shot, and if you run into trouble, post a question about the specific problem you run into.

Comment: I don't see any difference between E1 and E2. Why do you need multiple methods to begin with?

Comment: do you mean like creating a `private static boolean isDiscount(EObject e, WebOrder order)`? `EObject` for the E1 or E2 objects...

Comment: Since your code is identical, it seems you want to be parametrizing by whatever E1/E2 are.

Comment: I can only agree with the two comments above me. Just pass the E* Object as a parameter, or better yet, have the method _in_ the E* Object, as its generally not smart passing an object that you want to know something of (yes, not _always_)

Comment: I have multiple discounts 3 to be exact, each is flagged when used for verification and has a comment e1 e2 are just generic names for now. I am wanting to not reuse the code for each of them and figuring out if I can have a private method handle most of the code and some how not have repeated code for each public e1 e2 etc. I am new to Java and not really grasping this concept.

Comment: @micker each will be flagged for verify and have a comment for the parent company that has the discount.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible:

Just start a method with **private static**.

```
public static boolean isE2(WebOrder order)
{
  yourMethod(order);  
}

private static yourMethod(WebOrder order){
  //your code

   if(order.getPromos().stream().filter(i -> E1.contains(i.toUpperCase())).findFirst().isPresent())
{
  return true;
}
else
{
  List<Discount> discounts = new LinkedList<>();

 order.getItems().forEach(i -> discounts.addAll(i.getDiscounts()));

 if(!discounts.isEmpty())
 {
    return discounts.stream()
       .filter(i -> E1.contains(i.getCode().toUpperCase()))
       .findFirst()
       .isPresent();
 }
 else
 {
    return false;
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: how could I use all three discounts with the private static?

Comment: @Norcal Only add the common part in the the method! then modify the value in the two methods you posted.

Comment: Alright so lets say I have 


    private static final Set<String> E1 = Collections.unmodifiableSet(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("E1-Associate")));

and another that governs E2 discount codes...

would it be possible to use that format with lets say


private static final Set<String> PARENT_DISCOUNT = 


to = the E1 and E2 string?

Comment: @Norcal So you want to store E1 and E2 in PARENT_DISCOUNT?

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to handle having multiple discount codes with each having their own collection to make it into

filter(i -> E1.contains(i.toUpperCase()))

where the E1 would be something that covers all three discounts collections so each can still throw their own hold and comment

Comment: @Norcal Are you looking for something like like this `E1.addAll(E2)`;